# I can only fetch first data of url parameter in php

Tags: php

I have php code that like this

```
     print "<pre>";
    $string = http_build_query($data);
    echo "http://localhost:8888/moodle35/course/data.php?".$string;
    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8888/moodle35/course/data.php?".$string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, ture);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print "</pre>";
    return;
```

my url after http_build_query is:
 http://localhost:8888/moodle35/course/data.php?returnto=catmanage&fullname=MadanGurung&shortname=keg&category=1&visible=1&startdate=1530140400&enddate=1561676400&idnumber=&mform_isexpanded_id_descriptionhdr=1&summary_editor%5Btext%5D=&summary_editor%5Bformat%5D=1&summary_editor%5Bitemid%5D=538633179&overviewfiles_filemanager=479174445&format=topics&numsections=4&hiddensections=0&coursedisplay=0&addcourseformatoptionshere=0&lang=&newsitems=5&showgrades=1&showreports=0&maxbytes=0&enablecompletion=1&groupmode=0&groupmodeforce=0&defaultgroupingid=0&role_1=&role_2=&role_3=&role_4=&role_5=&role_6=&role_7=&role_8=&saveandreturn=Save+and+return&id=0

I can see returnto=catmanage&fullname=MadanGurung&shortname=keg and so on but I am not being able to fetch all

```
<?php
echo "something to print outside<\n>";
echo $_GET['returnto'];
echo $_GET['fullname'];
echo $_GET['shortname'];
?>
```

this code only print returnto value but not printing full name and short name. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show what is `$data`

Comment: try print_r($_GET); to see what you receive

Comment: Since you're POSTing to the URL, remove the string from the URL and use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` to get the variables back out.

Comment: I have solved the problem, when I printed print_r($_GET) it was adding amp; in front of the index in the array like [fullname] to [amp;fullname] except first item in the array. that is why I was able to fetch only first item. now, I change my http_build_query 

from $string = http_build_query($data);

to $string = http_build_query($data, '', '&');

now I am being able to fetch the data because this remove "amp;" from the index.
thank you